# Submit complex model on asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, model

I'm actually trying to submit a **whole page model** to the controller. The problem is that since the **model is a list of objects** referring to each other the form would be infinite. (At least if I do with it the traditional html form, I don't know better)

Now I'll enter into more details.

The **model** I use on my view is the following one:

```
public class MeasureModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TVList? tvList { get; set; }
}
```

Being the TVList class:

```
public class TVList
{
    public List<TVStandard> StandardsList;
}
```

And the TVStandard class a class inherited from:

```
public abstract class TVItem
{
    public string Name;
    public TVItem Parent;
    public List<TVItem> Children;
    public bool IsSelected = false;
}
```

And then  each class inherited from this one:

```
public class TVStandard : TVItem
{
    public string folderName;
}
```

```
public class TVSection : TVItem
{
    public string scriptName;
}
```

```
public class TVMode : TVItem
{}
```

```
internal class TVFreq : TVItem
{
    public string ID;
}
```

Once seen this, the only **attribute** that I want to change from the model before passing it to the controller is the `IsSelected` property. This property is changed through a series of **checkboxes** inside a treeview.
The rest will remain unchanged.
Here you can see the cshtml code:

```
<form method="post" action="/Launch/Home/retrieveSelection">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.tvList);
    <input type="number" name="Id" value="1234" style="display:none" />
    @*MIRAR PERQUE tvList SEMPRE ESTA A NULL   |||||   TESTEJAR SI EL QUE FALLA ES LA CHECKBOX A UN PROJECTE APART   |||||   PROVAR D'ENVIAR EL MODEL, SENSE CAP FORM*@
    <ul>
        @foreach (TVStandard tvstandard in Model.tvList.StandardsList) {
            int i = 0;
            <li>
                <input type="hidden" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].folderName" value="@tvstandard.folderName" />
                <input type="hidden" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Name" value="@tvstandard.Name" />
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvstandard.Name" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].IsSelected" value="true">
                <label for="@tvstandard.Name">@tvstandard.Name</label>
                <ul class="nested">
                    @foreach (TVSection tvsection in tvstandard.Children) {
                        int j = 0;
                        <li>
                            @* <input type="hidden" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].scriptName" value="@tvsection.scriptName" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].Name" value="@tvsection.Name" /> *@
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvsection.Name" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].IsSelected" value="true">
                            <label for="@tvsection.Name">@tvsection.Name</label>
                            <ul class="nested">
                                @foreach (TVMode tvmode in tvsection.Children) {
                                    int k = 0;
                                    <li>
                                        @* <input type="hidden" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].Children[@k].Name" value="@tvmode.Name" /> *@
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvmode.Name" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].Children[@k].IsSelected" value="true">
                                        <label for="@tvmode.Name">@tvmode.Name</label>
                                        <ul class="nested">
                                            @foreach (TVFreq tvfreq in tvmode.Children) {
                                                int l = 0;
                                                <li>
                                                    @* <input type="hidden" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].Children[@k].Children[@l].ID" value="@tvfreq.ID" />
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].Children[@k].Children[@l].Name" value="@tvfreq.Name" /> *@
                                                    <ul class="nested" style="display:block">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvfreq.Name" name="tvList.StandardsList[@i].Children[@j].Children[@k].Children[@l].IsSelected" value="true">
                                                        <label for="@tvfreq.Name">@tvfreq.Name</label>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                l++;
                                            }
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    k++;
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        j++;
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
            i++;
        }
    </ul>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="myULclass"/>
</form>
```

Being the model: `@model MeasureModel;`

So, eventhough I've tried to submit it by a classic **html form** or **Javascript** I've **not** been able to do it right.

**Does anybody know a possible way to do it?**

Comment: `So, evethough I've tried to submit it by a classic html form or Javascript I've not been able to do it right.` We need to see the code which you're using to build the model and submit it so that we can help you to debug it. While the code outlining the model itself is useful, it's not the part that needs debugging.

Comment: Okay, now I've edited the question. Thanks.